# HL7 FHIR IG Publisher returns java NullPointerException

Tags: hl7-fhir, publisher

I'm trying to generate documentation of my HL7 FHIR profiles using IG Publisher (`publisher.jar`). I'm running it on command line on macOS. I've uploaded the IG resource on Simplifier and it validates with no errors.
The problem is that i'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Full output below:

```
   java -jar publisher.jar -ig fsh-generated/resources/ImplementationGuide-nfz.pozplus.json -tx n/a
FHIR IG Publisher Version 1.1.120 (Git# 210e48f945ad). Built 2022-05-13T15:20:39.709Z (8 days old)
Detected Java version: 11.0.10 from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home on Mac OS X/x86_64 (64bit). 2048MB available
dir = /Users/marcingrudzien/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Osobisty/Praca/iEHReu/NFZ/POZ-Plus/FHIR/sushi-test/NfzTest, path = /Users/marcingrudzien/.gem/ruby/3.1.2/bin:/Users/marcingrudzien/.rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin:/Users/marcingrudzien/.rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
Parameters: -ig fsh-generated/resources/ImplementationGuide-nfz.pozplus.json -tx n/a
Start Clock @ sobota, 21 maja 2022 20:56:04 czas środkowoeuropejski letni (2022-05-21T20:56:04+02:00)

API keys loaded from /Users/marcingrudzien/fhir-api-keys.ini                     (00:00.0027)
Package Cache: /Users/marcingrudzien/.fhir/packages                              (00:00.0030)
Load Configuration from /Users/marcingrudzien/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Osobisty/Praca/iEHReu/NFZ/POZ-Plus/FHIR/sushi-test/NfzTest/fsh-generated/resources/ImplementationGuide-nfz.pozplus.json (00:00.0053)
Root directory: /Users/marcingrudzien/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Osobisty/Praca/iEHReu/NFZ/POZ-Plus/FHIR/sushi-test/NfzTest/fsh-generated/resources (00:00.0084)
Publishing Content Failed: null                                                  (00:00.0086)
                                                                                 (00:00.0087)
Use -? to get command line help                                                  (00:00.0087)
                                                                                 (00:00.0087)
Stack Dump (for debugging):                                                      (00:00.0088)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.initializeFromJson(Publisher.java:2947)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.initialize(Publisher.java:2168)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.execute(Publisher.java:854)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.main(Publisher.java:10144)
```

I hope someone here could help me. I could provide any additional information, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack dump, you are missing a "path" property in your json config file, but I highly recommend that you switch to using the new set up, a ini file that points to a template and a IG resource. Use something like the sample-ig as a starter (https://github.com/FHIR/sample-ig) or see the how-to (https://build.fhir.org/ig/FHIR/ig-guidance/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've switched to ig.ini. It looks like this: 
`[IG]
ig = fsh-generated/resources/ImplementationGuide-nfz.pozplus.json
template = fhir.base.template#current`

Unfortunatelly I still have NullPointerException, but now it fails on `determineActualIG` method. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.determineActualIG(Publisher.java:10274)
 at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.main(Publisher.java:10104)`

Comment: you need a -ig parameter.

Comment: Hmm... I have a ig parameter in my ig.ini. I thought it would be enough. If I add -ig I'm getting the same problem as in original question (Publisher.java:2947) :/

Comment: you should probably seek help here: https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179252-IG-creation